# Transitioning the gradient fill of a single node among many

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg, gradient

Let's say I have an SVG with a structure similar to this:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient-red">...</linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="gradient-blue">...</linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="50" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="100" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="150" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="200" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="250" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I now have five circles with reddish gradients. I understand how to change the color of a selected node -- I just target it (via `d3.select`) and alter its style to `'fill', 'url("#gradient-blue")`. But how would I go about ***transitioning*** the gradient fill from red to blue for that one node?

Something like this results in no tween/transition and instead causes an instant color swap:

```
d3.transition().duration(1000)
    .tween('start', () => {
        let test = d3.select(currentTarget);
        test.transition().duration(1000).style('fill', 'url("#gradient-blue")');
```

And if I were to transition the `stop-color` of the gradients themselves, it changes ***all*** of the nodes/circles (because you're altering the `<defs>`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Transition's interpolation

In D3, a transition basically interpolates a start value to an end value. This can be easy to demonstrate if we interpolate numbers. For instance, let's transition from `50` to `2000`:

```js
const interpolator = d3.interpolate(50, 2000);
d3.range(0, 1.05, 0.05).forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(interpolator(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

We can also interpolate strings:

```js
const interpolator = d3.interpolate("March, 2000", "March, 2020");
d3.range(0, 1.05, 0.05).forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(interpolator(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

#### The problem

Now, let's have a look at your case: you want to interpolate from this:

- `url("#gradient-red")`

To this:

- `url("#gradient-blue")`

What are the possible intermediates here? Can you see that this is impossible? Here is the proof:

```js
const interpolator = d3.interpolate("url(#gradient-red)", "url(#gradient-blue)");
d3.range(0, 1.1, 0.1).forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(interpolator(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the very first interpolation will instantly lead to the end value.

#### Possible solutions

The most obvious solution is interpolating the stop colour. However, as you just discovered, this will change the gradient of **all** circles.

So, the naive fix is creating several gradients, one for each circle, with unique IDs. While this may be an adequate solution for 3 or 4 circles, it's clearly not a clever solution if you have tens or hundreds of elements.

That being said, this is my suggestion:

1. Create a *temporary* gradient, let's give it the ID `#gradient-temporary`, just like the red one.
2. Then, when you select (or filter it somehow) a circle, change it's fill from `"url(#gradient-red)"` to `"url(#gradient-temporary)"`. This change is immediate, no effect is obvious on the screen.
3. Do the transition on the stop colour of this temporary gradient.
4. When the transition finishes, change the circle's fill from `"url(#gradient-temporary)"` to `"url(#gradient-blue)"`. Again, this is immediate. Also, change the stop colour of the temporary gradient back to red.

That way, you can have hundreds of circles, but you just need 3 gradients to transition them.

Here is a demo with that approach, click on each circle to transition it:

```js
const circles = d3.selectAll("circle");
circles.on("click", function() {
  const element = this;
  d3.select(element).style("fill", "url(#gradient-temporary)");
  d3.select("#gradient-temporary").select("stop:nth-child(2)")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("stop-color", "rgb(0,0,255)")
    .on("end", function() {
      d3.select(element).style("fill", "url(#gradient-blue)");
      d3.select("#gradient-temporary").select("stop:nth-child(2)")
        .style("stop-color", "rgb(255,0,0)")
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient-red" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(211,211,211);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="gradient-temporary" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(211,211,211);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="gradient-blue" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(211,211,211);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="20" cx="20" cy="70" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="20" cx="80" cy="70" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="20" cx="140" cy="70" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="20" cx="200" cy="70" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node">
        <circle r="20" cx="260" cy="70" style="fill: url('#gradient-red');"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am absolutely floored by the quality and comprehensiveness of this answer. Bravo, sir, and thank you. This nailed it.